# How to restart MySQL Fabric with authentication enabled?

Tags: mysql, mysql-fabric

I was working on a MySQL Fabric installation, and had been working with disable_authentication set to yes:

```
...
[protocol.xmlrpc]
address = 0.0.0.0:32274
threads = 5
user = admin
password = hunter2
disable_authentication = yes
realm = MySQL Fabric
ssl_ca =
ssl_cert =
ssl_key =
...
```

I set it to 'no', and ran `mysqlfabric manage stop` then `mysqlfabric manage start --daemonize`.  The client app broke, so I set disable_authentication back to 'yes' and ran `mysqlfabric stop` again to restart it, but I got:

```
Permission denied.
```

I looked through the documentation, both locally and at online, and haven't seen any way to pass a username and password to the `mysqlfabric` utility.  I tried `-u -p` as in MySQL and `--user` and `--password`, to no avail.  The latter gives

```
mysqlfabric: error: no such option: --password
```

Which seems to suggest that `--user` is a valid option, but I tried `--pass` and `-p` with no success.

I could probably just kill the process, but I'd like to know how to cleanly restart the server when authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plumbing around in the code for `mysqlfabric`, I noticed that it looked like the `mysqlfabric` utility was re-reading the newly-modified config file, seeing that `disable_authentication` was now set to 'yes', and thus clearing out any credentials, even if I specified them on the command line.

As far as I can tell, the running `mysqlfabric` instance still had credentials enabled, so when it was presented with the cleared-out credentials, it denied permission.

The solution was to change the config file back to `disable_authentication = no`, stop the server, *then* edit the config file to disable authentication, and start back up.

**Takeway lesson:**
Don't modify the Fabric configuration file while it's running, make sure to stop the server, edit the config, and then start it back up.

While I was at it, it seems that if you do need to specify a username/password, the command is indeed:

```
mysqlfabric manage stop --user=<username>
```

It will then prompt for a password.